# CSS Problem with Overflow width div Part 2

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, overflow

Related to this post

stackoverflow.com/questions/1736910/css-problem-with-overflow-with-div

The awser helped me ie: adding display: inline; 
i wanted to add some div into the div ".div-image" for title and description: i found that it worked if i replace display: inline; with display: inline-block; 
but guess what, it doesn't work with IE
[Example only working with Firefox](http://www.starsclips.com/testscripts/test-css-overfloat1.html)

Can someone have a idea what i should do for my horizontal scrolling div to work with IE to
Thank's for your help

Comment: you must add another div container between the image listing. and also add float: left; instead of display:inline-block in .div-image class

Comment: yeah this is the first thing a did from the first post and first exemple but it work only if i give a fixed width to this div, but i cant do that cause this will be a dynamic list generated and it can have 1 or hundred of block (div)

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can either go with just float-left or write a javascript function that'll do a replace for you based on whether it's ie or not.

Comment: float left doesn't work, it do a return and block appear under the first row